# Solve the following equation : $2(2(x^{2}-2)^{2}-7)^{2}-1=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve in $R$ the following equation :

$2(2(x^{2}-2)^{2}-7)^{2}-1=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$x=0$ clearly one  solution , but how I find other solutions 
How many solutions?

My attempt is put

$ y =\sqrt{1-x ^ 2} $

But I do not know how to solve  this type of equations?

Comment: I agree squaring can introduce extraneous solutions, but I disagree that $0$ is the only solution; see the answer by [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici)

Answer (score 3):

You must take care that squaring processes introduce extra roots.

In the present case, using the symmetry, I should simply plot the function
$$f(x)=2(2(x^{2}-2)^{2}-7)^{2}-1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and visually notice that there is a root close to $x=0.5$.

To *approximate* the root, use a Taylor expansion around this point to get
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{17}{32}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{49}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
   \right) \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this gives as an *estimate*
$$x=\frac 12+\frac{3 \left(16 \sqrt{3}-17\right)}{16 \left(147+2 \sqrt{3}\right)}\approx 0.513350$$ while the  solution is $\approx0.512603$.

**Added for your curiosity**

We could get a better approximation if, instead of using Taylor expansion, we use the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant. This would give as an *estimate*
$$x=\frac 12+\frac{6954 \sqrt{3}-7209}{310977+42536 \sqrt{3}}\approx 0.512572$$

Comment: By the symmetry you mentioned, if $x$ is a root, then so is $-x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. For sure ! I supposed (may be wrongly) that it was explicit.

Comment: Maybe it was; I'm not sure; anyway, yours is the only answer I like so far; +1; regards; and technically I would say the exact solution is *closer to* 0.512603

Comment: Are you saying that the exact solution is rational?!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Thank you ! I really wonder how, at precalculus level, could come this kind of problems. I suppose that teachers expect students to use graphic calculators, Wolfran Alpha and so on.

Comment: @TonyK. I never said that. I just gave a better approximation than $\frac 12$ which is clear from the plot.

Comment: You said "the exact solution is $0.512603$", which is a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

$X=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, replacing you have the equation $8X^8+32X^6-8X^4-80X^2-X+49=0$. It has $X=1$ and another positive ($<1$) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the left-hand side we get
$$8\,{x}^{8}-64\,{x}^{6}+136\,{x}^{4}-32\,{x}^{2}+1$$
squaring this term and subtracting $(1-x^2)$

$${x}^{2} \left( 64\,{x}^{14}-1024\,{x}^{12}+6272\,{x}^{10}-17920\,{x}^{
8}+22608\,{x}^{6}-8832\,{x}^{4}+1296\,{x}^{2}-63 \right) 
=0$$
by a numerical method we get the following solutions
$$-.5126032239, -.3954020655, -.3272996816, 0., 0., .3272996816, .3954020655, .5126032239$$

Comment: As a side note:  Render $y=2x^2$ in the 14-degree factor.  The resulting septic equation in $y$, multiplied by $2$ to clear a fraction, is $2$-Eisenstein irreducible.

Comment: **THIS DOESN'T SOLVE THE GIVEN EQUATION** Did you verify that the obtained numbers satisfy the given equation? I guess they (except $0$) make the left hand side negative, which is excluded.

Comment: I have squared two times so additional solutions are possible,